# Measuring infeasibility in convex optimization, relations with dual problem

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

A question regarding convex optimization and (maybe) duality.

I have a problem in the form
\begin{align}
x^* = \mathrm{arg} \min_x f(x) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad A x \leq b, C x = d,
\end{align}
where $f$ is either quadratic or, if it makes things easier, linear. Let's also assume that $P = \{ x \mid A x \leq b \}$ is bounded and not empty.

I would like to design an auxiliary optimization problem that:

- if the original problem is feasible returns the solution $x^*$ of the original problem,
- if the original problem is infeasible returns the minimum perturbation (according to some norm) $e^*$ that I should add to $d$ to make the problem feasible (remember $P \neq \emptyset$).

A naive approach could be, for example, something like
\begin{align}
\min_{x,e} f(x) + M \| e \| \quad \text{s.t.} \quad A x \leq b, C x = d + e,
\end{align}
where $M$ is "big enough". This however is very unpractical since the high value of $M$ would lead to numeric problems.

Do you have any better idea?

Do you think duality can help in some way here?
If I solve the dual of the original problem, and I detect unboundedness (we know that, under these assumptions, the primal infeasible implies the dual unbounded) can I elaborate the result to get something related to $e^*$?
For example, could an extreme ray of the dual feasible set help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If the primal is infeasible, the dual may also be infeasible. Why not solve 2 problems?

Comment: You could add a binary variable to deal with infeasibility, but I doubt it is faster.

Comment: In the quadratic case, the dual is always feasible, but in general you are right: the dual can also be infeasible. I guess solving two problems is always an option. I wanted to understand if I'm trowing away some useful information from the solution of the dual of the original problem.

Comment: This would be actually a lower level QP/LP solver of a branch and bound code for mixed integer programming (reason why I have the solution of the dual almost for free). Yes, the binary would work, but in practice it's equivalent to solve two problems...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the original problem is infeasible, you can just solve for
\begin{align}
\min_{x,e} \|e\|: & \\
Ax&\le b, \\
e &= d-Cx.
\end{align}

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know a priori if the problem is infeasible. Your approach would then boil down to just solve two problems, right?

Comment: You will have to first check the feasibility of the original problem anyway. Besides, this new problem is always feasible.

Comment: I do not agree that I have to first check the feasibility of the original problem anyway: the example I described with the big M in the objective function is a single problem, where I do not need that check first. No?

Comment: Your requirement is to solve for the original problem if the domain is feasible. Your objective function with the big M violates that requirement. The bigger the M is, the further away your solution deviates from the true solution, when the original problem is feasible. My formulation, on the other hand, fulfills exactly your two requirements.

Comment: When M is big enough the objective drives e to zero 
(if feasible) and I recover the original problem. No? It's like the big M method in linear programming.

Comment: I am sorry that I misspoke. I should have said that as $M$ is bounded, as large $M$ leads to numerical issues, the solution to your current objective function deviates from your exact requirements. My formulation, however, gives you exactly what you ask for.

Comment: It's clear that solving two problems as you are suggesting would work: my question is in fact how to avoid that...

Comment: Sure. But is there a computational problem checking the feasibility of the original problem? It should be easy by taking the most trivial objective function as the constraints are all linear.